# Create a Link to a Paypal setting the email address static

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

I have been researching up creating my own link to PayPal, that when a person is logged in, it will generate a "specified email" in the "To:" text box on the form.

However, I am planning something a tad more ambitious; I'd like to know it is possible to build this link in my code to where the specified email "cannot be edited or changed?" Again, this would coming from my custom-made link:

```
https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_send-money&nav=1&email=SomePresetEmail@mail.com
```

How can I code this to set "SomePresetEmail@mail.com" to be static?  Or is that even possible for me to do that, being I am not editing the code on Paypal's server side?  My site is currently built using Asp.Net WebForms.

Comment: DesignerMind if the answer is not suitable can you please provide a comment as to why instead of just down voting? It will help you greatly to help those helping you. Cheers

Comment: Nico... I apologize, but I have just returned to my computer, and happened to check and for responses. I was certain I logged out "hours ago," and thus I have not selected anything, as I haven't begun to read them. I noticed that for some reason, the site didn't log me out, although, I am certain I logged out explicitly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

DesignerMind,

I am not sure if I am following you correctly. But this link is displayed on the page to user and you want them to not be able to change the email?

Is it possible to have your link point to an address inside your application that gets redirected to Paypal?  When paypal recieves the request, they execute an internal mechanism to hash the request into a secured request variable. This means that when you navigate to the link the user is not seeing the actual link but a hashed version. A sample of the paypal hashed version is.

```
https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_flow&SESSION=Itqgb8iQ3mW92FT9ldzgcFmJyRVQLUpE2u9UMqeKbGmvwdMTY80oBEmo0SS&dispatch=5885d80a13c0db1f8e263663d3faee8def8934b92a630e40b7fef61ab7e9fe63
```

Now you could try to do this such as.

On your aspx.net page.

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="paypalLink" NavigateUrl="~/Paypal.aspx" />
```

or simply

```
<a href="/Paypal.aspx">Paypal</a>
```

And in the Paypal.Aspx code

```
static string SecretEmail = "someone@somewhere.com",
                PaypalRedirectFormat = "https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_send-money&nav=1&email={0}";

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect(string.Format(PaypalRedirectFormat, SecretEmail));
}
```

This is just an idea and actually if this is what you wanted a GenericHandler would do the job quite nicely.

Let me know if this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Nico, ok... now that I have actually read your response, let me address it. Again, I have no idea why your reply got down voted when I should have been logged out of the site.

Comment: @DesignerMind no problem.. Just was checking the downvote and was wondering how I can address this problem.. Let me know how this doesnt meet the requirements (maybe i missed something)... Cheers

Comment: Anyhow, your advice seems great. Problem is user who clicks this link must be logged in to their respective Paypal account 1st, so the link can populate a preset address in the textbox.  

My links purpose is to keep the user from changing the address in the box, so they can make proper fund transfers to the correct account via the email. Else, they could change it and send it wherever, or simply erase the input.

Paypal wont support the functionality at my acct level, so I figured I'd find a workaround. Not a code veteran yet, but learning ;) Long as my email can't be changed, I'm happy!

Comment: Lastly, I need to make two of these links; one for me, and one for my partner in the business. So, again, it's safeguard that my $$ isn't taken dishonestly. 

Thus, I am all ears now for your advice, and will attempt to change vote if I can. Didn't know my status allowed me to change votes yet.

Comment: @DesignerMind I dont believe paypal has an API that lets you query the users email address. The only way I know with paypal is for the user to approve your application to process payments automatically on their account. So back to the original question. The whole premise behind creating this link. Is this due to another user requesting a funds transfer? I am just trying to understand how this will be used. I do know that you wont be able to get the users email address from paypal.

Comment: I suppose the answer would be yes. When one of my affiliates completes a "sale" using our marketing system, they are compensated via Paypal. We charge a small commission on this compensation (i.e., $2.00 on $60.00 made). 

Paypal suggested using the "Transfer" option since we are all using personal accounts, else the $2.00 would subject to Paypal's fees, if receive by any means outside the transfer method, which is not subject to fees. 

Each partner's downline will click the link when a sale is done, so we can properly recoup the commission. Hence the email is my own acct email.

Comment: Thus, I am able to receive payment from my downline, without paying like 2.9% + $.30, on a modest $2.00 commission. The reason the address is to be "fixed," is to discourage dishonesty among my partner's downlines, who could as I mentioned earlier, just change the email, or simply erase it. We have monitoring system to catch if no commission was paid at all, but not if someone clicks the link, changes the email, and falsely claim they sent it.